# ng-style disable pointerEvents

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to disable a-href by using

```
var style ={};
style.zIndex = '10';
style.background = 'rgba(192,192,192,0.3)';
style.height= '100%';
style.top= '0';
style.left= '0';
style.right= '0';
style.pointerEvents = 'none';
return style;
```

at the controller side.

Html side:

```
<a href="#/tab/cases/case-detail/{{case.itemDetails.ID}}">
    <div style="width:80%; float:left;">
<table ng-init="sloppy = case" ng-style="calculateStyle(sloppy)">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Item Code: </strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{case.itemDetails.itemCode}}</td>
    </tr>   
    </table>

</div>
</a>
```

Currently, the overlay works but pointer event does not work.

Im using angular-js ng-style to do this. Am I doing it wrongly or have I used the wrong method? Is there any other way to disable a-href?

Comment: Can you post your html code.

Comment: You are using the `ng-style` on your table. How does this relate to your `<a href="...">` tag?

Comment: @muenchdo oh yeah. thanks for the heads up! so I should put it inside the table tag?

Comment: No, the `<table>` tag does not allow the `href` attribute (wouldn't make sense). You probably want the `ng-style` inside your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ng-style attribute needs to be on the `a` element to disable it, not on the `table` element.

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vypnv9r/

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <a href="#" onclick="alert('1')" ng-style="style">click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.style ={};
    $scope.style.zIndex = '10';
    $scope.style.background = 'rgba(192,192,192,0.3)';
    $scope.style.height= '100%';
    $scope.style.top= '0';
    $scope.style.left= '0';
    $scope.style.right= '0';
    $scope.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your ng-style to your anchor tag and make sure your style has scope.

html:

```
<a href="{{myLink}}" ng-style="style">Link to Disable</a>
```

controller:

```
 .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myLink = 'http://google.com';
    $scope.style = {};

    $scope.disableLink = function () {
      $scope.myLink = '#';
      $scope.style = {
         zIndex: '10',
         background: 'rgba(192,192,192,0.3)',
         height: '100%',
         top: '0',
         left :'0',
         right : '0',
         pointerEvents : 'none'
      }
    };

    $scope.disableLink();  //call this to disable
  });
```